# Azure B2C You are already registered, please press the back button and sign in instead

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-ad-b2c

I have created a custom `B2C_1A_SIGNUP_SIGNIN` Policy.

Used Google Authentication.

When I hit the create button `mypersonaltenantid` gets validated through a Azure Function.

I am presented the error message `You already registered, please press back button and sign in instead.`

[image]

Before executing this policy i made sure this user does not exist-

After the error message is displayed i look inside B2C: The user was created incl. my custom  claim with value `mypersonaltenantid`.

I was assuming that i am transferred to a different page after signup. Is this assumption wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a [Issue](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/issues/452) and got the final hint.

Looks like a action was performed **twice**. In my case I had a Base policy and a extension policy which had a `ValidationTechnicalProfiles` section.

`Base.xml`

```
<ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId" />
</ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
```

`Extension.xml`

```
<ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-ValidateTenantId" />
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId" />
</ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
```

My assumption after both files get merged:

```
<ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-ValidateTenantId" />
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId" />
</ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
```

But it looks like the merge is performed like this:

```
<ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-ValidateTenantId" />
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId" />
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId" />
</ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
```

Of course that explains why `AAD write` is performed twice.

From my point of view the error message is quite misleading.